# Menu bar doesn't free space in full screen mode

Tags: monterey, menu-bar, ui

On my MacBook I found, that menu bar doesn't deoccupy space on top of the screen. When mouse moves away from menu bar, it disappears, but blank space persists and remains unusable.

This is MacBook Pro 14 inch 2021 and it has camera in this area. May be they decided not to use this area bacause of this. But this causes certain applications to display bad.

How to fix?

Comment: Having the same problem, could not find a solution. Very annoying

Answer (score 1):

Inside `Applications` folder right-click application's icon and choose `Get Info` menu

[image]

then check `Scale to fit below built-in camera`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me!